# Javascript, Ember 2, How to refactor this code of promises (maybe also with async/await)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, async-await, refactoring

How can I refactor the code below?

```
get(category, "posts").then(posts => {
  return all(
    posts.map(post =>
      get(post, "words").then(words => {
        return all(
          words.map(word => {
            if (!get(word, "hasDirtyAttributes")) {
              return false;
            }
            return word
              .save()
              .then(() => this.ok())
              .catch(error => this.error(error));
          })
        );
      })
    )
  );
});
```

Also I would like to understand how to avoid having many functions when I have the following lint rule on this code:

```
[eslint] Use named functions defined on objects to handle promises (ember/named-functions-in-promises)
```

**How can I use async/await?**

Comment: How do you use the response of this function? Do you even need it? And what is `this.ok()` and `this.error()`?

Comment: Two little functions like this: `console.log(error)`. Anyway the problem is this code. How would you do that?

Comment: `get()` is a bit confusing. At first and second use, it appears to be *asynchronous* while at third use it appears to be *synchronous*. Which is it?

Comment: Best and simplest improvement would appear to be to flatten the code, giving a main chain comprising `get().then(posts => ...).then(words => ...).catch(error => ...)`, which is cleaner and the `.catch()` will be more comprehensive than in its current, nested scope. The `.then(() => this.ok())` expression should remain nested.

Comment: what is the goal of refactoring? You could "refactor" that code in any number of ways, you must have some idea of why you are "refactoring"

Comment: For example - your code is identical to `get(category, "posts").then(posts =>  all(posts.map(post => get(post, "words").then(words => all(words.map(word => get(word, "hasDirtyAttributes") ? word.save().then(() => this.ok()).catch(error => this.error(error)) : false))))));` - does that mean you should write it like that?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most complexity you can lose is by flatten the array of arrays. However this will not work if you need the result of that code. However I assume you just want to save all words.

Then I would do something like this:

```
get(category, "posts").then(posts => {
  return all(posts.map(post => get(post, "words")));
})
.then(wordOfWords => wordOfWords.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []))
.then(words => all(words.map(word => get(word, "hasDirtyAttributes") && word.save()))});
```

or with async functions:

```
const posts = await get(category, "posts");
const wordOfWords = await all(posts.map(post => get(post, "words")));
const words = wordOfWords.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
const wordsWithDirtyAttrs = words.filter(word => get(word, "hasDirtyAttributes"));
await all(wordsWithDirtyAttrs.map(word => word.save()));
```

However if  you really need this structure I would split your code up into multiple functions. Like `saveWordsForCategory`, `saveWordsForPosts`, `saveWords` and `saveWord`.